# Why opening after deleting doesn't call the onupgradeneeded callback

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I am using IndexedDB with latest chrome/chromium versions, and I still have the following problem.
I try to delete the DB before creating it, as you can see in the code below.

First time I execute this code, '*onupgradeneeded*' is correctly logged.
At this time, the DB exists.
Then if your run the same code, the database is correctly removed but the onupgradeneeded callback is not called again.

I don't find any information about that in the specs neither anywhere else. So if someone has an idea about how to solve this problem, I'm interested.

---

UPDATE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var module={

    dbName: 'myDB',
    dbVersion: 1,
    dbStores:[{name:'places', keyPath:'id'}],

    /* START :: DEFINE MAINONLINE INTERFACE FUNCTIONS */

    test: function(){
        var that= this;
        this.deleteDB()
        .then(function(e){
            return that.createEmptyDB(e);}
        )
        .catch(function(error){
            that.logError(error);
        });
    },

    logError: function(e){
        console.log('An error occured');
        if (e.target && e.target.errorCode){
            console.log('errorCode = ' + e.target.errorCode);
        }else{
            console.log(e);
        }
    },

    deleteDB: function(){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            var deleteDbRequest= indexedDB.deleteDatabase(this.dbName);
            deleteDbRequest.onsuccess= function(e){
                console.log('deleted successfully');
                resolve(e);
            }
            deleteDbRequest.onerror= function(e){
                console.log('error while deleting');
                reject(e);
            }
            deleteDbRequest.onblocked= function(e){
                console.log('blocked, unable to delete');
                reject(e);
            }
        });
    },

    createEmptyDB: function(event){
        var that= this;
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            var openDbRequest= indexedDB.open(that.dbName, that.dbVersion);
            openDbRequest.onerror= function(e){
                console.log('error');
                reject(e);
            }
            openDbRequest.onblocked=function(e){
                console.log('The open request is blocked');
            }
            openDbRequest.onsuccess= function(e){
                console.log('onsuccess');
                resolve(e);
            }
            openDbRequest.onupgradeneeded= function(e){
                console.log('onupgradeneeded');
            }
        });
    }
}

module.test();

</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delete won't work the second time because the database is open and therefor the "blocked" handler is invoked.

If you do it like this it works. Notice the onsuccess function which closes the db.

```
var delReq = indexedDB.deleteDatabase('myDB');
delReq.onsuccess= function(e){
    var openReq = indexedDB.open('myDB', 1);
    openReq.onupgradeneeded= function(e){
        console.log('Im called');
    }
    openReq.onsuccess = function() {
        openReq.result.close();
    }
}
delReq.onblocked = function() { console.log("blocked",arguments); }
```

**edit**

Also added some code for the onblocked event. If you comment out the `openReq.result.close()` code, you will see the `blocked` part

**edit2**

Your deleteDb function doesn't work, notice the `this.dbName`. `this` is window in your context. If you change it too:

```
deleteDB: function(){
    var that = this;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var deleteDbRequest= indexedDB.deleteDatabase(that.dbName);
        ....
```

When you execute this code.. you will again see the onblocked event being fired

**edit3**
Part of the spec where it makes deleting a `undefined` database succesfull: http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/Overview.html#dfn-steps-for-deleting-a-database --> If no database was found, then these steps are considered successful. Abort these steps

Comment: Yes you're right. But sorry, I have tried to make my code easier to read, and finally the problem was not really initial one :-/ . So I have updated the subject with a better sample. Try to reload the file several times...

Comment: Changed my answer because of you this variable :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, It was not related to indexedDB.
In my case, this.dbName is undefined. I should just use *that* instead.
Sorry for the error.

However, I don't undertand why deleteDabase(undefined) doesn't throw an error...

Comment: lol, just edited my answer than I saw this... I noticed the same thing with the this.dbName

Comment: Part of the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/Overview.html#dfn-steps-for-deleting-a-database --> If no database was found, then these steps are considered successful. Abort these steps

Comment: it does seem like an odd decision to include in the spec. My guess is the API designers wanted that method to be idempotent.